# Use base function but only with specific class

Tags: r, class

Names are getting hard to come by these days.  It seems with additional packages we'll need to eventually use names like `a_function_to_find_the_correlation_of_a_data_set_but_slightly_different`.

My question is as follows:

**How can one use the name of a base function (`cor` for example) for use in a package as a function name that operates on a specific class and if it is not of that class then the original use of `cor` from the base stats package is assumed?**

Here is an example:

```
cor(mtcars[1:4, 1:4])

## > cor(mtcars[1:4, 1:4])
##             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
## mpg   1.0000000 -0.9753429 -0.4962289 -0.9753429
## cyl  -0.9753429  1.0000000  0.6755988  1.0000000
## disp -0.4962289  0.6755988  1.0000000  0.6755988
## hp   -0.9753429  1.0000000  0.6755988  1.0000000

cor <- 
function (x, ...) {
    UseMethod("cor")
}

dat <- "I wish robots would disappear."
class(dat) <- c("whammy_robots", class(dat))

cor.whammy_robots <- function(x, ...) {
    gsub("robots", "", x)
}

cor(dat)

## > cor(dat)
## [1] "I wish  would disappear."
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "whammy_robots" "character"    


cor(mtcars[1:4, 1:4])

## > cor(mtcars[1:4, 1:4])
## Error in UseMethod("cor") : 
##   no applicable method for 'cor' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Is there a way to say hey if the object isn't of this class (`whammy.robots` for instance) then behave as you typically do `cor`?

I assume I could make specific new methods fucntions like:

```
cor.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
   stats::cor(x, ...)
}
```

and

```
cor.matrix <- function(x, ...) {
   stats::cor(x, ...)
}
```

but this gets convoluted fast.

Comment: That's what default methods are for... `cor.default <- stats::cor` (not to say whether masking a base-ish package function is a good idea or not).

Comment: Ahh gotcha I think Josh, let me play around.

Comment: @Josh can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving aside the point that what you want to do might not be a good idea...

You don't have to define a method for every possible class.  That's what default methods are for.

```
> cor.default <- stats::cor
> cor(mtcars[1:4, 1:4])
            mpg        cyl       disp         hp
mpg   1.0000000 -0.9753429 -0.4962289 -0.9753429
cyl  -0.9753429  1.0000000  0.6755988  1.0000000
disp -0.4962289  0.6755988  1.0000000  0.6755988
hp   -0.9753429  1.0000000  0.6755988  1.0000000
```

Comment: sometimes it makes sense if you are using your function in a very similar context but needs a slight tweak.  Thank about a `tm::TermDocumentMatrix`, let's say is named `tdm`.  `cor(tdm)` won't work but it may be very handy to have a `cor` function/method that will use `as.matrix` first.  I agree this needs to be done thoughtfully and with care but can be a good thing as you're building off of the semantics of the base function.  Plus Hadley does it with `filter` in dplyr so it must be ok :-)